# They would have liked (their friend to drink less) or (that their friend drink less)

Tags: subjunctives, tense-agreement

How should it be:

> 1) They would have liked their friend to drink less.
>
> 2) They would have liked that their friend drink less.

If none of the two sentences is correct then how should I say?

Comment: Present Perfect is a pointless distraction that has no relevance to the usage being queried. ***They would like** him to drink less.* Note that idiomatically today we don't usually attach ***that-*** clauses to ***like*** (but we still do with ***prefer***). Hence *I would **like him to go***, but *I would **prefer that he goes*** (or *I would **prefer that he go***, but that's a declining "subjunctive"  usage, so best avoided).

Answer (score 2):

Sentence 1 appears to be correct.

The second is grammatical, but literary or archaic. With "liked it that" it would be a little more natural, but still a bit literary, definitely not something you would hear someone say in conversation.

although,

> If none of the two sentences

should be

> If neither of the two sentences

Comment: I would say that the second is grammatical, but literary or archaic. With "liked it that" it would be a little more natural, but still a bit literary.

Comment: I would agree with that, definitely not something you would hear someone say in conversation unless they fumbled their words.

Comment: Now, I have another question. In a written text, can I use the two versions (1) and (2), especially when talking about people who lived more than 100 years ago.

Comment: @ColinFine With sentence #2 you need to change "**drink**" to "**drinks**"

Comment: "that he drink less" is a correct use of the subjunctive.